# Necessary and Sufficient

Tags: digital-logic

Consider 4 kinds of necessity and sufficiency for a truth.

> A condition which is necessary and sufficient for something to be true
>
> A condition which is necessary but not sufficient for something to be true
>
> A condition which is not necessary but sufficient for something to be true
>
> A condition which is not necessary and not sufficient for something to be true.

Define a logic block made of AND/OR with 8 inputs and 1 output.

The one output is the state of the truth.

The eight inputs consist of **2** of each of the 4 conditions shown above. Its obvious that some do not connect to any logic.

What would it look like?

Comment: sniff, sniff, I smell homework! What have you done so far?

Comment: No its not homework. Its trying to understand "necessary AND sufficient" as opposed to "sufficient but not necessary" Also, I re-edited it for clarity.

Comment: A, that is a more to the point question. You could have included that!

Answer (score 1):

A is necessary for B means not(a) => not(b)

A is sufficient for B means a => b

Sufficient but not necessary is the same, but it explicitly states that not(a) /=> not(b)

This is predicate logic, it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: This is not helpful at all. Many engineering theorems and statements use " necessary and sufficient", or "Sufficient but not necessary" or "necessary, but not sufficient"

Comment: That might be true, but how does that lead to "not helpful at all"? I gave you the interpretation of all 3 phrases you quote.

Comment: If you cannot answer the question, please do not say it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: I did answer the question, and it is about predicate logic, so I don't see why I should not state that. But you did not clarify which part of your question you think I did not answer.